# hover effect jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of li elements that I want to alternate in color using odds and evens, and then highlight based on mouse hover. In order to un-highlight I need to keep track of what the color used to be, odd or even. To do this when I apply the highlight color, I first set an arbitrary attribute to it. Are there any downsides to doing it this way? Is there a better way? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var init = function(event){
$("li:odd").css({'background-color' :  '#eeeeee', 'font-weight' : 'bold'});
$("li:even").css('background-color', '#cccccc');  
    //initial colors setup

    $("li").hover(
    function ()   //hover over
    {
        var current = $(this);
        current.attr('old-background', current.css('background-color'));
        current.css('background-color', '#ffee99');

    }
    , function()  //hover out
{
    var current = $(this);
    current.css('background-color', current.attr('old-background'));
})

}
$(document).ready(init);
</script>
```

So is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use addClass and removeClass to achieve this, instead of manipulating the CSS directly.

```
<style>
  li.hover {
    background-color: #ffee99 !important;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var init = function(event){
    $("li:odd").css({'background-color' :  '#eeeeee', 'font-weight' : 'bold'});
    $("li:even").css('background-color', '#cccccc');  
    //initial colors setup

    $("li").hover(
      function ()   //hover over
      {
        $(this).addClass('hover');

      }
      , function()  //hover out
      {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      })
    }
    $(document).ready(init);
```

Comment: This is a better practice indeed

Comment: classes for odd and even as in the other answers is also a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

I agreen with benlumley, you should use addClass/removeClass methods.

Your CSS may look like,

```
li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.odd {
    background-color: '#eee';
}

li.even {
    background-color : '#ccc';
}

li.hover {
    background-color : '#ffee99';
}
```

Your init function will now look like,

```
var init = function(event)
{
    $('li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('li:odd').addClass('even');

    $('li').hover(  function()
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('hover');
                    },
                    function()
                    {
                        $(this).removeClass('hover');
                    }
                   );

}
```

This code has advantage that if you want to change the styling of how those list items look, you can go to your CSS code and change the colors without touching your JS code!

Comment: If you've added odd and even classs, you don't need JavaScript code for hover. The hover can be done in CSS.

Comment: Disagree. I am adding 'odd'/'even' CSS class using jQuery so that it works across all browsers. Similarly, using jQuery's hover method makes sure that the above code will work in IE6.

Comment: Oh that's right. CSS hover only works with <a> on IE6. Curse you, IE6!

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a CSS class called `highlighted` and call `current.addClass('highlighted')` to add on hover over and `current.removeClass('highlighted')` to remove the class on hover out. I assume you are also adding odd and even classes into your CSS file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var init = function(event){
    //initial colors setup
    $("li:odd").addClass('odd');
    $("li:even").addClass('even');  

    $("li").hover(
        function ()   //hover over
        {
                $(this).addClass('highlighted');

        }
        , function()  //hover out
        {
                $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
        })

}
$(document).ready(init);
</script>
```

`highlighted` should be declared after `even` and `odd` classes in your file in order to be able to override the default colors.

Comment: He is using jQuery so :even and :odd selectors will work without problem. And good point about the order in which classes have to appear in CSS. My code sample already put them in right order but I forgot to make a note in the code about it.

Comment: I noticed he was using :odd and :even as jQuery selectors right after I initially posted it and removed that hint immediately. Thanks for the note anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

like the other yo can also use

```
$("li:odd").toggleClass("odd");
```

or

```
$("li:even").toggleClass("odd");
```

if you like to change the color of the first item. (also you can use first I think)